# Assigning to an incomplete instantiated class

Tags: python, class

In Python, do I have to worry about assigning an instance attribute to refer to an "incomplete instantiated" class (forgive me if I'm using the wrong terminology)? For instance:

```
class Child:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.p = parent
        print(self.p.x)

class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.c = Child(self)

a = Parent()
```

This prints '1', so it works. But are there any gotchas to this kind of design? Would referring to a yet-to-complete instantiated Parent class be a problem inside Child.**init**? Thanks for any help to a newbie.

Comment: What happens if you try to make an instance of child?

Comment: The biggest problem is that you've created a circular reference between these two objects that will confuse the garbage collector and may keep them from being deleted while the program is running, eventually eating through all memory. The child-to-parent back reference should be a [weakref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#module-weakref).

Comment: Merely setting a reference to the object (apart from weakref above) is harmless though. Its a different thing if you try to call a method on the partially initialized object - that method may touch things that have not yet  been initialized.

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble to answer this!